# Is it possible to unit test multitouch on android?

Tags: android, unit-testing, instrumentation

I've been trying to make a unit test for an application I'm writing. I want to test the graphics performance on various zoom operations, but I can't seem to figure out how to send events that contain two pointers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This was not possible before API 9/Android 2.3/Gingerbread. The method [`MotionEvent#obtain`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MotionEvent.html#obtain%28long,%20long,%20int,%20int,%20int%5b%5d,%20android.view.MotionEvent.PointerCoords%5b%5d,%20int,%20float,%20float,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int%29) can be used to create a `MotionEvent` containing multiple pointers, which you can then dispatch to your views for testing. (Remember to `recycle()` the `MotionEvent` when you're done with it.)